# Can I change the update mode of a TYPO3 installation from composer to automatical?

Tags: composer-php, typo3, upgrade

I migrated a TYPO3 installation, that has been installed via Composer,
to another webspace/hoster and now I want to run an update.

If I try to do this in the backend

```
[Login]>Admin tools>Upgrade>Update TYPO3 Core>Update Core
```

I get the message that I could update via Composer only
and this information about a variable:

```
TYPO3_DISABLE_CORE_UPDATER=1
```

[image: I get the message]

Now, can I change the update mode from Composer to automatical updates
in the backend, p.e. by changing the variable (if yes, where)?

If nothing works, can I update manually?

I didn't find specific answers here or on google when searching for
'typo3 changing update/upgrade type/mode'.

Comment: You should work on your google skills ;-)
Manually you can update via composer: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/Composer/Index.html#update-typo3-core

Comment: I will try to  improve and look into this, thanks.

Comment: Hi Julia, my problem was, that I wanted to update completly without composer. But out of despait I tried to do it manually and got the message 'expecting color, list received error using scss'. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231292/expecting-color-list-received-error-using-scss-via-typo3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried to switch back from a composer based installation to the old school way of updating TYPO3 installations. If there is any chance to use composer at your new webhoster, you should do so! I'd never choose a webhoster who doesn't offer SSH. If you have SSH you can install composer manually if it's not provided.

I've tried this with a fresh TYPO3 10.4 installation and it seemed to work.
**But these instructions come with no warranty!**

1. **Backup your webspace and database! Really, don't skip this!**
2. `rm -rf composer.* vendor/`
3. `cd public` (maybe your document root directory has a different name like web)
4. `wget --content-disposition https://get.typo3.org/10.4.5`
5. `tar xzf typo3_src-10.4.5.tar.gz`
6. `ln -s typo3_src-10.4.5 typo3_src`
7. `rm -rf typo3 index.php`
8. `ln -s typo3_src/typo3`
9. `ln -s typo3_src/index.php`
10. Go to the TYPO3 Install tool (/typo3/install.php)
11. Maintenance => Rebuild PHP Autoload Information => Dump autoload
12. Maintenance => Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache => Flush cache

But beware, I've not tested that with a full blown TYPO3 installation. After the switch you might need to reinstall all your extensions.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'm working on a hosted server that doesn't give me root rights. I could ask for a composer installation but our hoster is a little bit reluctant when it comes to additional installations. So I'll try to do it with the tools I have. It'll take a little time but I will post my experiences then.

Comment: You don't need root access to use composer. SSH access with limited rights will also work! Composer is just a PHP script. Download the phar file manually. But as said, I would rather change the webhoster than work with a non-composer installation.

Comment: The composer update asked me for a git during the process which I can't install, but I succeeded in updating the Typo with composer on my local Xampp. I now have another issue which I posted here. First, I need a running version but I'll try updating manually using your instruction.

Comment: You should not run Composer as root. Also, a better practice than running Composer on the production machine may be setting it up elsewhere and deploying it to  production. How to deploy - there are numerous ways. Search for "deployment" or "deployment" and "composer". (This also means there is no requirement to install composer on the production server if you do it that way, which is not a bad thing but a good thing). This is a general explanation, not TYPO3 specific: https://nystudio107.com/blog/executing-atomic-deployments

Comment: Concerning my initial problem: I learned that the colleague who installed the application in the first place changed something in the source code, prior to my attempts to update. I relaunched the installation, there wasn't too much content to copy and from there I can update the common way. - To Sybille: I tried to update a copy on my local server, never on the productive server. Thanks for the hint.